# Solving an Olympiad functional equation $f(f(n))=f(f(n+2)+2)=n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} $ such that$f(0)=1$ and $$f(f(n))=f(f(n+2)+2)=n. \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$

My approach:
Plugging in some values, it is not hard to see that $f(n)=1-n$ satisfies the given relation. I claim that $ f(k)=1-k $ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I just cannot see a way to use the relation and induct on $k$ to prove my hypothesis. Am I missing something obvious? Please help as I am new to functional equations. Also please share some online resources to solve functional equations as I am preparing for Olympiads.

Thank you.

Comment: "I claim that $ f(k)=1-k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ": you just said that it holds for *all* $k$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust shouldn't I do that for some k to proceed with my induction hypothesis?

Comment: You say "it is not hard to see that $f(n)=1−n$ satisfies the given relation", don't you ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm sorry I didn't mean that. i actually meant to point out what i thought the function according to me is, to the viewers of this question.

Comment: @User12992  You just make two separate inductions.  Note from Saad's soln that $f(1)=0$ and $f(0)=f\big(f(1)\big)=1$.  The first induction is: $f(n)=-n+1$ for non-negative integers $n$.  The base cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are already established.  The second induction is: $f(-n)=-(-n)+1=n+1$ for non-negative integers $n$.  The base case $n=0$ is already established.  Another base case to be established is $n=1$ (i.e., show that $f(-1)=2$).  There is no need to create a bounty for this.  If this answers your question, then feel free to award the bounty to Saad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$f(f(n)) = n \ (\forall n \in \mathbb{Z})$ implies $f$ is injective, thus$$
f(f(n)) = f(f(n + 2) + 2) \Longrightarrow f(n) = f(n + 2) + 2. \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Also$$
0 = f(f(0)) = f(1),
$$
then$$
f(n) = -n + 1 \quad (\forall n \in \mathbb{Z})
$$
can be proved by induction.

Comment: How do I proceed with the inductive step?

Comment: First using $n = 0, 1$ as base cases to prove for $n \geqslant 0$, then using $n = 0, 1$ as base cases to prove for $n < 0$.

Comment: Please check this: suppose that $f(k)=1-k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have $f(k)=f(k+2)+2$ which implies $f(k) > f(k+2)$ which implies $f(k) \geqslant f(k+1)$. But $f(k) = f(k+1)$ implies $0=1$ which is absurd. Therefore $f(k) > f(k+1)$ thus forcing $f(k+1) = -k$. (It can be seen using the relation that $f(k+2)= -1-k$)

Comment: No need to be so complicated since $f$ has the recurrence relation $f(n + 2) = f(n) - 2$ with initial conditions $f(0) = 1$, $f(1) = 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: That $+2$ inside the recurrence function is making it difficult for me to induct on consecutive integers, instead I am ending up inducting on consecutive integers with same parity.

Answer (score 1):

**Complement:** By induction $f(n) = -n + 1 \quad (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})$. Note that $f(-n) = n + 1 \quad (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})$. This proves the assertion for all integers.